# WebRequest 400 bad request to api

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, instagram-api

I am making webrequest to instagram api, and recieving 400 bad request, but i guess this is not something specific to instagram and is a generic error in my code.
here is my code."code" paramter in this request is obtained from previous request.Code breaks at "GetResponse" method

```
  string clientID = "myclientid";
  string clientsecret="myclientsecret";
  string redirectURL = "http://localhost:64341/"; 
 string webrequestUri = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/
  access_token?  client_id=" + clientID + "&client_secret=
  " + clientsecret +   "&grant_type=authorization_code"                                            + "&redirect_uri="redirectURL+"&code="
+Request.QueryString["code"].ToString();
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(webrequestUri);
request.Method = "POST";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at what a valid request looks like?

Comment: instagram documentation says 
curl \-F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=YOUR-REDIRECT-URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token

I am not a php guy unfortunately.

Comment: Is this correct? "&grant_type=authorization_code"                                            + "&redirect_uri="redirectURL+"&code="
+Request.QueryString["code"].ToString();

Comment: What happens when you simply browse requesturi in browser?

Comment: it becomes a blank webpage

Answer (score 1):

C#/asp.net Working example:

```
namespace InstagramLogin.Code
{
    public class InstagramAuth
    {
        private InstagramClient myApp = new InstagramClient();

        public string genUserAutorizationUrl()
        {
            return String.Format(myApp.OAuthAutorizeURL, myApp.ClientId, myApp.RedirectUri);
        }

        public AuthUserApiToken getTokenId(string CODE)
        {
            //curl \-F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
            //-F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
            //-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
            //-F 'redirect_uri=YOUR-REDIRECT-URI' \
            //-F 'code=CODE' \https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token

            var wc = new WebClient();
            var wcResponse = wc.UploadValues(myApp.AuthAccessTokenUrl, 
                                new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection() { 
                                    { "client_id", myApp.ClientId }, 
                                    { "client_secret", myApp.ClientSecret },
                                    { "grant_type", "authorization_code"},
                                    { "redirect_uri", myApp.RedirectUri},
                                    { "code", CODE}
                                });
            var decodedResponse = wc.Encoding.GetString(wcResponse);
            AuthUserApiToken UserApiToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthUserApiToken>(decodedResponse);

            return UserApiToken;
        }
    }
}
```

your object:

```
    namespace InstagramLogin.Code
    {
    public class InstagramClient
        {

            private const string ApiUriDefault = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/";
            private const string OAuthUriDefault = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/";
            private const string RealTimeApiDefault = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/";

            private const string OAuthAutorizeURLDefault = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&response_type=code";
            private const string AuthAccessTokenUrlDefault = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";

            private const string clientId = "clientid";
            private const string clientSecretId = "clientsecretid";
            private const string redirectUri = "http://localhost/InstagramLogin/InstaAuth.aspx";
            private const string websiteUri = "http://localhost/InstagramLogin/InstaAuth.aspx";

            public string ApiUri { get; set; }
            public string OAuthUri { get; set; }
            public string RealTimeApi { get; set; }


            public string OAuthAutorizeURL { get { return OAuthAutorizeURLDefault; } }
            public string ClientId { get { return clientId; } }
            public string ClientSecret { get { return clientSecretId; } }
            public string RedirectUri { get { return redirectUri; } }
            public string AuthAccessTokenUrl { get { return AuthAccessTokenUrlDefault; } }
//removed props
    }
    }
```

instagram loged user:

```
namespace InstagramLogin.Code
{
    public class SessionInstaAuthUser
    {

            public bool isInSession()
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthUserApiToken"] != null;
            }

            public AuthUserApiToken get()
            {
                if (isInSession())
                {
                    return HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthUserApiToken"] as AuthUserApiToken;
                }
                return null;
            }

            public void set(AuthUserApiToken value)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthUserApiToken"] = value;
            }

            public void clear()
            {
                if (isInSession())
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthUserApiToken"] = null;
                }
            }

    }
}
```

markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnInstaAuth"
        Text="Click here to get instagram auth"
        runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
//objects
private InstagramClient InstagramApiCLient = new InstagramClient();
        private InstagramAuth AuthManager = new InstagramAuth();
        private SessionInstaAuthUser SesssionInstaUser = new SessionInstaAuthUser();
```

//click login with tests - user is logged (in session)

```
void btnInstaAuth_Click(Object sender,
                               EventArgs e)
        {
            btnGetInstaPosts.Visible = false;
            if (SesssionInstaUser.isInSession())
            {
                SesssionInstaUser.clear();
                Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
                clickedButton.Text = "Click here to get instagram auth";
                btnInstaAuth.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect(AuthManager.genUserAutorizationUrl());
            }
        }
```

You can find what you need in this class **InstagramAuth** sorry if I did forgot to remove some of extra methods or properties, please strip it out.

This button can be used on all page, still don't forget to add on page load at the page set in instagram as login page, query string parse:

```
//here you read the token instagram generated and append it to the session, or get the error :) 

    if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    if (!SesssionInstaUser.isInSession())
                    {
                        if (Request.QueryString["code"] != null)
                        {


                            var token = AuthManager.getTokenId(Request.QueryString["code"]);
                            SesssionInstaUser.set(token);
                            //set login button to have option to log out
                            btnInstaAuth.Text = token.user.username + " leave instagtam oAuth";
                            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString().Split('?')[0]);
                    }
                    else
                        if (Request.QueryString["error"] != null)
                        {
                            btnInstaAuth.Text = Request.QueryString["error_description"];
                        }
                }
            }
```

Sorry If I'd missed something, php curl in to c# is implemented in first class.

**Update (I did forget something), insta user obj :)**

```
namespace InstagramLogin.Code
{
    public class UserLogged
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
        public string profile_picture { get; set; }
    }

    public class AuthUserApiToken
    {      
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public UserLogged user { get; set; }
    }
}
```